# Using Google Fonts on JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I want to use Montserrat from Google font. I put the following in vendor.scss:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
```

And use it in home.component.html like the following:

```
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">Maecenas tortor nunc, tempor id massa vel, scelerisque malesuada urna. Nunc laoreet maximus velit.</p>
```

But it doesn't work. The web page only displays sans serif.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Montserrat too, but locally. But it's not important in your case.

My css:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: local('Montserrat-Regular'), url("../myfonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
   unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

In your case adapte `url()`

and I defined it on my css for all pages like that

```
body {
   background: #fdead6;
   font-family: "Montserrat", Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
   /* Montserra bug fix for IE */
   -ms-font-feature-settings: normal;
   /*color: #282828;*/
}
```

In your case you can use a class on your css

```
.myMontserratFont{
    font-family: "Montserrat", Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
    /* Montserra bug fix for IE */
    -ms-font-feature-settings: normal;
}
```

and use it on your html page :

```
<p class="myMontserratFont">Maecenas tortor nunc, tempor id massa vel, scelerisque malesuada urna. Nunc laoreet maximus velit.</p>
```